# MVC3 could not be installed in xp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Friends Initially there was problem in the re installation of VS 2010 in my computer with Xp.
But i was able to install recently and every thing goes fine. I was able to use MVC 2 and other features. But when i tried to install MVC 3 i could not get success.THe installation process Roll back giving the message of FATAL ERROR DURING INSTALLATION.

Then i check in the error and found that Microsoft ASP.NET webpages 1.0 was missing in my computer.Is that the problem for installing MVC 3? or other .

I have attached the  screen shot of error. I will be thankful for the solution.
[image]

Sorry, i couldn't upload clear picture.But Error shown was as follows:

**Returning IDOK, InstallMessage_error[This product Requires Microsoft Asp.net web Pages 1.0. Please install the missing component, then try to install this product again.]**

**strong text**

Comment: The screenshot is illegible, you should upload a hi-res version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) will probably be the easiest way for you to solve your dependency installation problems. Using the installer will give you the ability to select and download/install a variety of products. For instance take a look at the follow screen shot:

[image: Web Platform Installer and download page]

Under the **Products** tab, you have the ability to select MVC3, ASP.NET web pages, MVC3 Updates, etc. Since some products depend upon others the Web Platform Installer will also manage these dependencies for you when installing your selected items.

Good luck, and hope this helps you some.